# Fragment.java Rewarded Ad Implement Problem

Tags: android, error-handling, android-fragmentactivity

*I have made an Apps, but when I put the code of RewardedAd in Fragment.java, I can't find the keyword "this" correctly, which is giving Code Error. Now, what can I do to solve this error?**

````
    public HomeFragment() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    }
    FragmentHomeBinding binding;
    FirebaseFirestore database;
    private RewardedAd mRewardedAd;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        binding = FragmentHomeBinding.inflate(inflater, container, false);

        AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().build();

        RewardedAd.load(this, "ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/5224354917",
                adRequest, new RewardedAdLoadCallback() {
                    @Override
                    public void onAdFailedToLoad(@NonNull LoadAdError loadAdError) {
                        // Handle the error.

                        mRewardedAd = null;
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onAdLoaded(@NonNull RewardedAd rewardedAd) {
                        mRewardedAd = rewardedAd;

                    }
                });```
````

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in the context. One of the parameters of the `load()` method is the context you pass this to. But the main problem is that when working with fragments, we must use the Activity context. Here is the **solution** to your problem - write `requireActivity()` instead of `this` and it will work.